# C++ - Unhandled exception when using atoi()

Tags: c++, exception, atoi, unhandled

When using this code, it throws an unhandled writing exception, which I'm almost certain is to do with the atoi() function.

```
while(true){
                    char* item = "";
                    cin >> item;
                    int numItem = atoi(item);
                    if(numItem){
                        if(numItem<=backpackSpaces){
                                equipItem(backpack[numItem]);
                                break;
                        }else{
                            cout << "No such item." << endl;
                        }
                    }else if(item == "back"){
                        cout << "Choose an option from the original choices. If you can't remember what they were, scroll up." << endl;
                        break;
                    }else{
                        cout << "Command not recognised." << endl;
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
char item[20];
```

`char * item = ""` makes item point to read-only memory - you're trying to modify it. Pointers to string literals are better written as `const char * item = ""` - then the compiler will make sure you don't modify it. The reason `char * item = ""` is legal is backward compatibility with C.

Comment: I knew there was something to do with an array in it >.> Thanks

Comment: Even better, use `std::string`.

Comment: @Pig Head: use strcmp not == to compare C strings. Or just do what everyone suggests, use std::string :)

Comment: I'll use strcmp - I was using std::string but you can't convert them to integers with atoi().

Comment: @Pig Head: Sure you can, atoi(str.c_str())

Comment: @Pig Head: C++0x introduces `stoi` if you have it, otherwise you also have `boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);` (which throws if this is no number you've stored here).